# ios - Restkit and SSL certificate error

Tags: ios, web-services, tomcat, ssl, restkit

I have a tomcat server that uses a self signed SSL certificate and is running a web service. I am trying to connect to the web service with Restkit. However, I am getting an error related to certificate validity. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL];

RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
client.disableCertificateValidation=YES;

RKRequest *request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/addEvent?deviceID=%@&eventID=%@",deviceID,eventID]];
request.disableCertificateValidation=YES;
request.delegate=self;
RKResponse *response = [request sendSynchronously];
```

This request fails with the following error:

```
2013-01-09 15:11:53.931 Mobile_ACPL[5761:907] The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “notify.acpl.lib.in.us” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I get this error even though I have set disableCertificateValidation to YES. How can I get this working?

**EDIT:** I attempted adding the certificate as shown here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/131

I still get the same result.

**EDIT 2:** It looks like the error message is being set at this line in RKRequest.m:

```
    payload = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_URLRequest returningResponse:&URLResponse error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURLConnection does not cater for [authentication challenges](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1) in synchronous calls. You need to make asynchronous calls for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was setting disableCertificateValidation on RKClient but I was using a RKObjectManager which used a different RKClient. The following line, placed after the RKObjectManager initialization, did the trick:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.disableCertificateValidation = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using RestKit using

```
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

won't work, instead do this:

if you added rest kit manually to your project, click on RestKit.xcodeproj go to project > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros

and add `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_=1`

thats finished.